# Tell Glassfish to Use Existing Zip File

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2 with Dojo 1.7 and would like to shorten the build process, it's taking quite a while for maven to copy the dojo js files each build. I could use the CDN version dojo but I would like to be able to debug when offline.  Is there a way to tell Glassfish to use the pre-zipped dojo source file?  Just to be clear, I don't want Glassfish to zip the files for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you place the desired resources in an independent WAR file, and deploy separately?  You'll have a context path to the resources (diff URL) that is dependent on the new WAR file, but you'll be able to deploy it once.

If that's not satisfactory, you could alternatively write a small servlet (packaged in your normal app) to expose resources that you locate (*.getClass().getResourceStream()) from a jar file you've placed in `glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`.  This is trivial to do via a restful-ws, also some libraries (primefaces) facilitate exposing resources.

Comment: I am giving this a try. What would be the path to files in the jar? Something like, "http://localhost:8080/<ApplicationName>/lib/dojo-release-1.7.2/... ?"

Comment: That I don't know.  How are they packaged today?  If they're in a resource folder in your war, do you have any control over the URL by which they are accessed?

Comment: It's in a folder with the rest of the html pages. I.e. in Netbeans <Project>/Web Pages/js/dojo/...  I can move them but of course the js files need to be accessible from the html files located in the <Project>/Web Pages folder.

Comment: So this isn't going to work for you then - as it's a set of resources (*.js), and not java class files.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting workaround, though I was hoping for something more elegant.  I suppose I could just put the js files on Apache and essentially run a local cdn.